# Radon-Nikodym derivative of mutually absolute continuous measures

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, radon-nikodym

Here is the problem I have. $\nu$ and $\mu$ are two positive $\sigma$-finite measures, such that $\nu \ll \mu$ and   $\mu \ll \nu$. Also, the function $h$ is the Radon Nikodym derivative such that $h = \frac{d\nu}{d\mu}$. What is then $\frac{d\mu}{d\nu}$?

I get lost in the notation here a bit but I guess the first R.N. derivative implies that

$\nu(E)=\mu(1_Eh)$

The second one should similarly imply that
$\mu(E) = \nu(1_Eh)$

for some function $h$ and a set $E$.

Is there anything more to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\frac {d\mu} {d\nu} =\frac 1 h$. Note that $\nu\{h=0\}=\int_{\{h=0\}} h d\mu =0$ so $\frac 1 h$ is well defined almost everywhere with respect to $\nu$.

Comment: ok, that makes sense given the notation, but how do you show that $\frac{d\mu}{d\nu}=\frac{1}{h}$?

Comment: $\nu (E) =\int_E h \, d\mu$. From this we can show that $\int g \, d\nu =\int gh \, d\mu$ for all simple functions $g$, hence for all non-negative measurable functions $g$. Now just take $g=\frac 1 h I_E$.

Comment: ah, so proof by standard machine. that makes sense. thanks

Comment: one more question. I'm stuck at this point - how do you show that $\int g d\nu = \int gh d\mu$ for all non-negative measurable functions? I can only see it for a characteristic function... Also how does this extend to all non-negative measurable functions. Don't I need a monotone convergence to show that?

Comment: Any non-negative measurable function $f$ is the increasing limit of a sequence of simple functions and we can apply Monotone Convergence Theorem.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, is it possible to somehow say $\mu(E)=\int_E \frac{d\mu}{d\nu}\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}d\mu$ for all measurable $E$ and then somehow conclude $\frac{d\mu}{d\nu}\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}=1$?

Comment: @edamondo Yes, that is a correct argument.